# Mapa de calor desde diccionario

Tags: python, matplotlib, lista

tengo un diccionario y me gustaria crear un mapa de calor o heatmap o densitymap de unos valores concretos. Solo consigo plotear los puntos pero no el mapa de calor. Esto es lo que tengo.

```
for id,msj in diccionario.items():
    pylab.plot(msj['Longitud'],msj['Latitud'],'.')
```

Con lo anteior funciona perfectamente y puedo ver la figura de todos los puntos ploteados, pero lo que necesito es un mapa de calor, he probado con esto, pero no funciona.

```
for id,msj in diccionario.items():
    plt.hexbin(msj['Longitud'],msj['Latitud'])
```

msj[longitud] y msj[latitud] son listas. El error que obtengo es:

> ValueError: First argument must be a sequence

Alguna idea?

Tal vez existe alguna otra forma de crear un mapa de calor, no me importa usar otro metodo o libreria.

EDIT:

Lo he solucionado haciendo uso de dos variables, `lon` y `lat` con este codigo:

```
lon=[]
lat=[]
for id,msj in diccionario.items():
    lon.append(msj['Longitud'])
    lat.append(msj['Latitud'])
plt.hexbin(lon,lat)
```

He probado a usar tambien hist2d y obtengo algo como esto.

[image: figuras]

Hay alguna forma de obtener algo mas "bonito"? del tipo esto:

[image: map]

Comment: ¿Que tipo de dato contienen `msj['Longitud']` y `msg['Latitud']`? `int`, `float`, `str`, etc Sería de gran ayuda si pudieras aportar un ejemplo mínimo del contenido del diccionario para poder emular tu problema.

Comment: Lo he solucionado guardando los valores en dos variables `lon` y `lat` y despues haciendo `plt.hexbin(lon,lat)`.

Answer (score 1):

¿Has visto esta [librería](https://plot.ly/python/heatmaps/)?

Tomado de la página principal

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go

data = [
    go.Heatmap(
        z=[[1, 20, 30],
           [20, 1, 60],
           [30, 60, 1]]
    )
]
py.iplot(data, filename='basic-heatmap')
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quizá pueadas hacer una matriz con los valores de tus listas `lan` y `lon` y despues remplazarlo por z en el objeto `go.Heatmap`

Sin un ejemplo mínimo, no puedo proporcionar una mejor respuesta, lo siento.

Comment: Gracias pero busco algo como la ultima foto.